# basic varnish 4.0 setup doesn't seem to work

Tags: centos, varnish

**[Apparently I was running varnishd as root]**

Now, I get this:

```
[gideon@mywebsite ~]$ sudo varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,128m -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:8000 -d
[sudo] password for gideon: 
Platform: Linux,2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
200 284     
-----------------------------
Varnish Cache CLI 1.0
-----------------------------
Linux,2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8
```

---

I have a VERY simple setup. Perl Webapp running on `0.0.0.0:5000` and I want varnish to cache this. The system is a virtual *"droplet"* (or VM) on http://www.digitalocean.com.  The machine is a **CentOS box**.

Inside `/etc/sysconfig/varnish/` I have:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,128m"
```

Inside `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` I have:

```
backend default {
  .host = "0.0.0.0";
  .port = "5000";
}
```

I've tried a number of things no luck. (Restarts, alternative configs etc.) I can access my app at website.com:5000 just fine.

This is what I got when I used `varnishd`:

```
$varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl 
                    -s malloc,128m -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:80 -d
Failed to create ./vcl.jAoXC8Rf.c: Permission denied
```

I tried searching various posts, (some on SF) all lead to dead ends or solutions for completely different situations.

I bet there's something very basic I'm doing wrong but I've even gone to the point of killing my machine, starting off from a clean VM, installing perl and the modules I need, then got my app working, then installed BASIC varnish setup from the docs. I did this TWICE!

Any help and pointers will be appreciated tremendously.

Comment: Are you starting `varnishd` as `root`?

Comment: @PaulHaldane yes, I tried with local user+sudo, updated question.

Comment: btw. you say varnish 4.0, but you actually have `varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8`

Answer (score 1):

```
backend default {
  .host = "0.0.0.0";
  .port = "5000";
}
```

This is your problem. You can not have backend at 0.0.0.0. You probably want to use 127.0.0.1 instead.

(0.0.0.0 is used to tell system to listen for connections to any IP, but is not a valid IP to connect to)

Edit: ok i was too quick to answer. This won't fix the permission issue. Give  me a second.

Edit2: ok, rereading i see you fixed the permission issue, so my solution should fix the non-working backend.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on the directory where varnish compiles the vcl to, Ubuntu uses /var/lib/varnish/ Try chmod 666 -R /var/lib/varnish/

From your code above you're not running as root, try testing as root or using sudo. If it works, then the permissions are the problem.

Comment: Does it apply to centOS (I'm on there).. I'll try it soon...

Comment: If it does work running as root. Search for a file vcl.( random characters).so this will be in the directory you need to change the permissions on.